# Using aggregate and join on all columns except a few

Tags: python, pandas

I want to join the rows and apply all comma separated variation to the final row of each group, and I group it by  the column *Name*

Reproducible code and data frame representation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog"],
                     "Name": ["Walter", "Walter", "Alfonso", "Alfonso", "Alfonso"],
                     "col3": ["Beer", "Wine", "Cider", "Cider", "Vodka"],
                     "Description": ["I like cats, Walter and alcohol", "I like cats, Walter and alcohol", 
                                     "I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol","I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol",
                                     "I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol"]})

+------+---------+-------+----------------------------------+
| Col1 |  Name   | Col3  |           Description            |
+------+---------+-------+----------------------------------+
| Dog  | Walter  | Beer  | I like cats, Walter and alcohol  |
| Cat  | Walter  | Wine  | I like cats, Walter and alcohol  |
| Dog  | Alfonso | Cider | I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol |
| Dog  | Alfonso | Cider | I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol |
| Dog  | Alfonso | Vodka | I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol |
+------+---------+-------+----------------------------------+
```

So far I have used this code `df.groupby('Name').agg(', '.join)` and `for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].str.split(", ").map(set).str.join(", ")` to do this operation, but it messes up my Description column which includes free text with a bunch of commas. There will never be any variation in the description field within each group.

I want this output, where you can see that the description column is untouched.

```
+----------+---------+--------------+----------------------------------+
|   Col1   |  Name   |     Col3     |           Description            |
+----------+---------+--------------+----------------------------------+
| Dog, Cat | Walter  | Beer, Wine   | I like cats, Walter and alcohol  |
| Dog      | Alfonso | Cider, Vodka | I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol |
+----------+---------+--------------+----------------------------------+
```

I have tried this:

```
##remove Description column
listColumns = list(df.columns)
listColumns.remove('Description')

##
df = df.groupby('Name')[listColumns].agg(', '.join)
df = df.reset_index()

##remove string separated duplicates
for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].str.split(", ").map(set).str.join(", ")
```

But this removes the *Description* column from the dataframe entirely.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible remove duplicated with all columns use lambda function with `set`s and `join`:

```
df = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg(lambda x : ', '.join(set(x)))
print (df)
      Name      col1          col3                       Description
0  Alfonso       Dog  Vodka, Cider  I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol
1   Walter  Dog, Cat    Beer, Wine   I like cats, Walter and alcohol
```

If order and performance are important use `dict.fromkeys` for remove duplicates:

```
df = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg(lambda x : ', '.join(dict.fromkeys(x).keys()))
print (df)
      Name      col1          col3                       Description
0  Alfonso       Dog  Cider, Vodka  I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol
1   Walter  Dog, Cat    Beer, Wine   I like cats, Walter and alcohol
```

If real data are different and need only first value of `Description` column per groups:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['Description']), lambda x : ', '.join(set(x)))
d['Description'] = 'first'

df = df.groupby('Name').agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      Name      col1          col3                       Description
0  Alfonso       Dog  Vodka, Cider  I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol
1   Walter  Dog, Cat    Beer, Wine   I like cats, Walter and alcohol
```

Answer (score 1):

`groupby().agg()`:

```
df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Description'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())
```

Output:

```
      Name     col1         col3                       Description
0  Alfonso      Dog  Cider,Vodka  I like dogs, Alfonso and alcohol
1   Walter  Dog,Cat    Beer,Wine   I like cats, Walter and alcohol
```